# link_to update for a nested resource not working

Tags: put, link-to, nested-resources

The link in _applicant.html.erb looks like this in the browser: `http://localhost:3000/needs/3/applicants.1`
and when clicked on this shows up in the browser:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [PUT] "/needs/3/applicants.1"
```

I want it to update the acceptance column for this particular applicant row. Basically I want it to send data to the update method of the applicants controller. How can I modify the code to do this?

_applicant.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Accept Applicant', need_applicants_path(applicant.need_id, applicant.id), :method => :put, :action => "update", :applicant => {:acceptance => true} %>
```

got this from running rake routes:

```
PUT    /needs/:need_id/applicants/:id(.:format)      applicants#update
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :needs, except: [:new] do
 resources :applicants
end
```

applicants_controller.rb

```
class ApplicantsController < ApplicationController

  def update
    @need = Need.find(params[:need_id])
    @applicant = @need.applicants.find(params[:id])

    if @applicant.update_attributes(params[:applicant])
      flash[:success] = 'Your applicant has been accepted/rejected!'
      redirect_to @need
    else
        @need = Need.find(params[:need_id])
      render 'needs/show'
    end

  end


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two possible fixes here:

First,

```
http://localhost:3000/needs/3/applicants.1
```

should probably read

```
http://localhost:3000/needs/3/applicants/1
```

The error is in this line:

```
<%= link_to 'Accept Applicant', need_applicants_path(applicant.need_id, applicant.id), :method => :put, :action => "update", :applicant => {:acceptance => true} %>
```

where...

```
need_applicants_path(applicant.need_id, applicant.id)
```

You can try passing in two instance objects like so:

```
need_applicants_path(Need.find(applicant.need_id), applicant)
```

Second, another possible solution is to explicitly set the PUT path in your routes.

In your config/routes.rb add the line

```
put 'need/:need_id/applicant/:id/update
```

then run

```
rake routes
```

and see what the PUT path is

Comment: Hey thanks Rich. I ended up doing this and it got it working:

<%= link_to 'Accept Applicant', need_applicant_path(:need_id => applicant.need_id, :applicant_id => applicant.id, :applicant => {:accepted => true}), :method => :put, :action => "update" %>